# Are CourseIDs in google classroom API unique across domains?

Tags: google-classroom

I am planning to use the classroom assigned course id to store a license (whether this course is licensed) on our server. Can I assume that the classroom assigned course id is unique across all domains i.e. the following situation **cannot** arise -

district A -> School B - Course C (classroom assigned id = 35595)

district B - > School D - Course F (classroom assigned id = 35595)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, based on the document:

> ## [API overview](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started#api_overview)
>
> [*Course metadata and aliases*](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started#course_metadata_and_aliases)
>
> - A [Course resource](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses) represents a class, such as "M. Smith's 4th period math," and its assigned teachers, student roster, and metadata.
>
> *Each course is identified by a unique ID assigned by the server*. Additionally, names may be associated with a course and used in place of the unique ID. Each name, called an [Alias](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.aliases), exists in a namespace that restricts who can create and view it.

Base on the sample Java code:

```
Course course = new Course()
.setName("10th Grade Biology")
.setSection("Period 2")
.setDescriptionHeading("Welcome to 10th Grade Biology")
.setDescription("We'll be learning about about the structure of living creatures "
+ "from a combination of textbooks, guest lectures, and lab work. Expect "
+ "to be excited!")
.setRoom("301")
.setOwnerId("me")
.setCourseState("PROVISIONED");
course = service.courses().create(course).execute();
System.out.printf("Course created: %s (%s)\n", course.getName(), course.getId());
```

It is generated by the server. Hope it helps!

Comment: Verified with Google Classroom support too. The assigned ids are unique across domains, the aliases are not.